# Putting the results of a query into new table in SQL Server

Tags: sql

I want to insert query results into new table is there any way I can make changes in code so that it gets stored in a table.

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 a.DocEntry
    ,b.TrgetEntry
    ,b.itemcode
    ,a.DocNum AS 'Order No.'
    ,a.CardCode
    ,a.CardName
    ,b.DocDate AS [Delivery No.]
    ,c.targettype AS 'Ctargettype'
    ,c.trgetentry AS 'Ctargetentry'
    ,c.itemcode AS 'c-itemcode'
    ,c.docentry AS 'Cdocentry' a.CancelDate
    ,a.Project
    ,a.DocStatus
    ,b.ObjType
    ,a.ObjType
FROM ORDR a
INNER JOIN rdr1 b ON a.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
LEFT JOIN dln1 c ON c.TrgetEntry = b.DocEntry
    AND b.itemcode = c.ItemCode order by c.itemcode;
```

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Chose table aliases that make sense, like `o` for `ORDR` etc. Much easier to read, and write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as it will create a new table and insert the records into that table. If you have already created table then you can give name and individual columns also for both insertion and selection.

```
SELECT *
INTO YourTableName
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 5 a.DocEntry
        ,b.TrgetEntry
        ,b.itemcode
        ,a.DocNum AS 'Order No.'
        ,a.CardCode
        ,a.CardName
        ,b.DocDate AS [Delivery No.]
        ,c.targettype AS 'Ctargettype'
        ,c.trgetentry AS 'Ctargetentry'
        ,c.itemcode AS 'c-itemcode'
        ,c.docentry AS 'Cdocentry' a.CancelDate
        ,a.Project
        ,a.DocStatus
        ,b.ObjType
        ,a.ObjType
    FROM ORDR a
    INNER JOIN rdr1 b ON a.DocEntry = b.DocEntry
    LEFT JOIN dln1 c ON c.TrgetEntry = b.DocEntry
        AND b.itemcode = c.ItemCode
    )

a
```

For using order by clause you can try something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT   
        Insured_Customers.FirstName, Insured_Customers.LastName,   
        Insured_Customers.YearlyIncome, Insured_Customers.MaritalStatus  
INTO Fast_Customers from Insured_Customers INNER JOIN   
(  
        SELECT * FROM CarSensor_Data where Speed > 35   
) AS SensorD  
ON Insured_Customers.CustomerKey = SensorD.CustomerKey  
ORDER BY YearlyIncome;
```

You can learn in detail about [**INTO Clause Here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: if my query has order by clause then this method is giving error . Error :The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: @Adi In that case you should modify your question and put your original issue what your facing for inserting rows from select output is correct here. There is no need or order by I think for inserting records.

Comment: @Adi Even now I can't see order by clause in your question/post.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like SQL Server code.  In that database, you add `into` after the `select` clause:

```
Select distinct top 5 o.DocEntry, r.TrgetEntry, r.itemcode, o.DocNum as order_num, o.CardCode,
       o.CardName, r.DocDate as delivery_num,
       d.targettype as Ctargettype, d.trgetentry as Ctargetentry,
       d.itemcode as c_itemcode, d.docentry as Cdocentry
a.CancelDate,a.Project, a.DocStatus,b.ObjType,a.ObjType
into <new table>
from ORDR o inner join
     rdr1 r
     On o.DocEntry = r.DocEntry left join
     dln1 d
     on d.TrgetEntry = r.DocEntry and
        d.itemcode = r.ItemCode;
```

Note that I changed the table aliases so they are *meaningful*.  Arbitrary letters are very hard to follow.  Table abbreviations are more useful.

I also changed the column aliases so they do not need to be escaped.  Do not make troublesome aliases!